# How to send a SIGTSTP signal to a process spawned by an expect script

Tags: bash, signals, expect, jobs

I wrote an `expect` script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn sql "user=xx dbname=xx"

interact
```

After I entered the `sql` client, I can't send the **SIGTSTP** signal by `ctrl + z` to make the current process suspend and go to the background.

The terminal will only show:

```
=> ^Z
```

What should I do to make `ctrl + z` achieve the above purpose?

Answer (score 5):

The [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) of `expect` gives the recipe:

> During interact, raw mode is used so that all characters may be passed to the current process. If the current process does not catch job control signals, it will stop if sent a stop signal (by default ^Z). To restart it, send a continue signal (such as by "kill -CONT "). If you really want to send a SIGSTOP to such a process (by ^Z), consider spawning csh first and then running your program. On the other hand, if you want to send a SIGSTOP to Expect itself, first call interpreter (perhaps by using an escape character), and then press ^Z.

So, you may be able to do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn /bin/sh
exp_send "psql hostaddr=xxxx  port=xxxx  user=xx dbname=xx\r"

interact
```

For example, let's consider the following interactive shell script named `interact.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

read -p "First name: " fname

read -p "Last name: " lname

echo "you entered: $fname $lname"
```

And the following expect script named `script.exp` to automate the previous one:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn /bin/sh

exp_send "./interact.sh\r"

interact
```

We launch the latter:

```
$ ./script.exp 
spawn /bin/sh
./interact.sh
$ ./interact.sh
First name: Stack
Last name: ^Z  (we entered CTRL-Z here)
[1]+  Stopped(SIGTSTP)        ./interact.sh
sh-4.4$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped(SIGTSTP)        ./interact.sh
sh-4.4$ fg
./interact.sh
Overflow
you entered: Stack Overflow
$ exit
exit
$
```